# curly braces in HTML

Tags: html, phpbb

I see curly braces in HTML code to be used to separate the logic (PHP) from the view (HTML) but I can't understand it..

for example in phpBB:

```
<h3>{L_BIRTHDAYS}</h3>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at is parsing code. the php parser will consume the html and when it comes across a pattern, in this case {} it will look in its property bag and substitute the values for the variable names inside the {}

You can read more about this sort of thing by googling rendering engines.